# Training sliding window model on larger images in Keras (tf backend)

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

guys.

I am relative new to machine learning and programming in Keras/Tensorflow. I have taken a course in machine learning for image analysis, but I'm struggling with a rather simple issue (I believe). My task is to detect noise on images which typically are on the size 2200x630, give or take a few hundred pixels. This is too large to feed into conv-layers, and I cannot really resize it. This is because I am (at a later point) going to reproduce the images without noise.

I have looked into standard CNNs with multiple layers etc. I have no problems creating these in Keras, but the issue strikes when I try to use a sliding window.

**How do I train a network while using sliding windows?**

I can't seem to wrap my head around it. In my case, I simply want the network to decide if there are noise present in the image or not. So it's a simple True/False question, a cnn with 2 classes. After "breaking" the image into multiple pieces with sliding windows, how does one adjust the label for the entire image for backprop and training afterwards? Is it even possible to do this in Keras? I do not have any code, since I have no idea how to advance further. Therefore I'm posting a pseudocode here:

```
Class Network():
      def __init__(self):
          .......


      def model(self):
          img = Input(self.img_shape)
          model.add(Conv2D(........)
          ......
          ......
          model.add(Dense(nclasses))
          return model
```

The part above here is kind of normal (I hope), but the one I'm struggling with is the following:

```
class Network......

    def sliding_window(self):
        for i in range(start, stop):
            for j in range(start, stop):
                 img = data[window_size*i:window_size*(i+1)][window_size*j:window_size*(j+1)]

    def training(self):
        .....
        .....
        for X_target, labels in generator():
             window = sliding_window(X_target)
             self.autoencoder.train_on_batch(X_train,X_target)
```

How do I now make the program understand that 20 images equals one image and that all the labels of the last 20 images have to be combined to make a wholesome label for the actual image. The layers themselves are defined for small boxes, so how do I even train the network? Am I going about this all wrong? Should I use something else than a sliding window? I am so confused....

Comment: I don't understand "I cannot really resize it". What you do at a later stage with another network doesn't really matter, in this network you can start with a layer (deterministic or convolutional) that downsizes to treatable. OTOH, if you have a "diffuse" noise (e.g. w/ white noise, averaging gives too good" image), you can simply train a CNN on random sub-images of your training set (duplicating the same y). In prediction, you apply the net to a bunch of subfigures (e.g. grid) and use the multiple True/False to get a single one (simply by voting, or a further CNN), although it'll be slow...

Comment: This will be the start of what is to become a u-net or an autoencoder which first labels noise, then (if present) removes it. The images has high complexity in detail, and since I am to recreate them, I cannot resize them too much. Does that makes sense?

I wish there was constant noise around the image, like gaussian/white noise or similar. This noise is typically present in just parts of the image. More like a precise spiking noise. I guess I really cannot use sliding window, since multiple of the subfigures will be without noise, even though the total image has noise present.

Comment: If you know how to solve problems you probably don't have to care about the True/False to begin with, just create the U-Net or whatever to clear up noise, if it must be able to only correct a part of faulty picture it must also be able to not correct it at all if it's already fine. I remember of a paper (unfortunately I can't find it anymore) where CNN were used to remove anomalies like entirely missing parts of the picture, it worked even without any training (just using the rest of the image). If your images are homogeneous enough in style, it might work even for you...

Comment: That might just work! Gonna try and see what I can get done with a U-net/autoencoder. Hoping it'll work out. Thanks for helping me think outside of my own head. Got stuck in my own thoughts.